# converting material ui functional component Mini variant drawer to class component Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am using mini variant drawer from material-ui official website

**https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#drawer**

I am trying to convert into class component, but alot of issues, craches comes up. Some of them are hooks related and occurs through node modules.
Can any body have used this component in class component

```
  import React from 'react'
  import clsx from 'clsx'
  import {
    createStyles,
    makeStyles,
    useTheme,
    Theme
  } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
  import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer'
  import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'
  import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar'
  import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
  import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline'
  import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
  import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider'
  import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
  import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'
  import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft'
  import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight'
  import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'
  import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon'
  import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText'
  import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox'
  import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail'

  const drawerWidth = 240

  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
      root: {
        display: 'flex'
      },
      appBar: {
        zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
        })
      },
      appBarShift: {
        marginLeft: drawerWidth,
        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
        })
      },
      menuButton: {
        marginRight: 36
      },
      hide: {
        display: 'none'
      },
      drawer: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
      },
      drawerOpen: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
        })
      },
      drawerClose: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
        }),
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
          width: theme.spacing(9) + 1
        }
      },
      toolbar: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
        // necessary for content to be below app bar
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar
      },
      content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(3)
      }
    })
  )

  export default function MiniDrawer () {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const theme = useTheme()
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true)

    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
      setOpen(true)
    }

    const handleDrawerClose = () => {
      console.log('close clicked =')
      setOpen(false)
      console.log('open =', open)
    }

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
          position='fixed'
          className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
            [classes.appBarShift]: open
          })}
        >
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              color='inherit'
              aria-label='open drawer'
              onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
              edge='start'
              className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
                [classes.hide]: open
              })}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant='h6' noWrap>
              Mini variant drawer
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
          variant='permanent'
          className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open
          })}
          classes={{
            paper: clsx({
              [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
              [classes.drawerClose]: !open
            })
          }}
        >
          <div className={classes.toolbar}>
            <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
              {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? (
                <ChevronRightIcon />
              ) : (
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              )}
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Drawer>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />
          <Typography paragraph></Typography>
          <Typography paragraph></Typography>
        </main>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hooks in a class component. Create a state property in your class and use it instead.

From react docs: [Converting a Function to a Class](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class)

> You can convert a function component like Clock to a class in five steps:
>
> - Create an ES6 class, with the same name, that extends React.Component.
> - Add a single empty method to it called render().
> - Move the body of the function into the render() method.
> - Replace props with this.props in the render() body.
> - Delete the remaining empty function declaration.

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have another issue, relating hooks